# Finding a single attribute of a MAX value

Tags: sql, oracle, max, aggregate

I have 2 tables `Corporations` (business_id,corp_name) and `Positions` (business_id, salary, location)`

> I'm trying to find the name of the corporation with the highest paid
>   position in a specific location.

ex. What corp has the highest paid position in Orlando?  (I just want the Corp name and Salary to show up like (NASCAR, 90000))

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM Positions
WHERE location = 'Orlando'
GROUP BY compid
```

However instead of 1 result I get all corporations and their position salary for Orlando.

Comment: SQL is a programming language. Which DBMS are you using? MySQL, DB2, Postgres, SQLite, ...?

Comment: And your code has `compid` while the table definitions do not !?

Comment: One of the solutions is to put a `correlated sub-query` into `WHERE` clause.

Comment: how would I structure a correlated sub-query

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the two tables in order to get the business name. You don't tell us what compid is but that is why you are getting multiple results - one for each comp_id.

Assuming business_id is the foreign key to corporations, this should get you what you need.

```
SELECT Corporations.Corp_Name, MAX(Positions.Salary)
FROM Positions
INNER JOIN Corporations ON Corporations.Business_id = Positions.Business_id
WHERE Positions.Location = 'Orlando'


If comp_id is your foreign key, use this
SELECT Corporations.Corp_Name, MAX(Positions.Salary)
FROM Positions
INNER JOIN Corporations ON Corporations.Comp_id = Positions.Comp_id
WHERE Positions.Location = 'Orlando'
```

Comment: This gives me an ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
error

Comment: Which one of the two queries?

Comment: Try adding GROUP BY Positions.Business_ID at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Code for ISO/ANSI standard SQL:

```
SELECT c.comp_name, p.salary 
FROM Positions  p
  JOIN Corporations  c
    ON c.business_id = p.business_id
WHERE p.location = 'Orlando'
ORDER BY p.salary DESC
  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY ;
```